# Automatically detect series Excel

Tags: excel, charts

I want to make a dot chart in Excel 2016 of a series of data which can vary. This data looks like this:

```
Category    Actuations  Parameter A Parameter B Parameter C
Device 1    1   85.6    2.6 18
Device 1    2   94  3.5 15.4
Device 1    3   14  1.8 21.3
Device 1    4   79  4.9 16.2
Device 2    1   69  6.7 20
Device 2    2   87  5.4 13.7
Device 2    3   85  2   9.9
Device 2    4   49  6.3 10.3
Device 3    1   97  4.5 10.9
Device 3    2   93  8.1 11.6
Device 3    3   79  9.7 13.5
Device 3    4   67  12.4    16.8
```

[image]

In my dot chart I want to format those different categories in a different way (marker color).

How can I do this?
Is it best to make a graph per column or can I do this all together?

Comment: Are you referring to a chart like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/87KDX.png  ?

Comment: @ashleedawg: Yes indeed!

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the data

[image: ex1]

2. on the `Insert` tab, choose a chart type in the `Charts` category.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I think I understood your first graph incorrectly. 
You see, I want to have the x-axis state the number of actuations (not devices). And my series have to be grouped by device. So for every device I have 4 actuations with 4 different Y values (Parameters)...

Comment: That makes 2 of us!  I don't understand what you wanted since the question isn't very clear at all but tried to help anyway. I saw the words `dot chart` in your question, I've never heard of that kind of chart so I [Googled it](https://www.google.ca/search?q=dot+chart+excel), the first search result was [How to create dot plot in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2232-excel-dot-plot.html), I figured you must have the name wrong, I took the 20 seconds to make a Scatter Chart of your data (which also is meaningless without explanation), and then you said it was correct. [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing question, I will definitely check your link, thanks.
Thank you for trying!!